# DataWeave not reading XML correctly

Tags: xml, mule, dataweave, mule4

I'm trying to read an XML file and run some formatting to convert it to a plain text file but DataWeave fails to read the XML file correctly and errors out.

Here is my input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ds:tfmDataService xmlns:nxcm="urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:flightdatacommonmessages"
    xmlns:fdm="urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:flightdata"
    xmlns:ns4="urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:ficommondatatypes"
    xmlns:ds="urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:tfmdataservice"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns6="http://www.fixm.aero/tfm/3.1"
    xmlns:ns8="http://www.faa.aero/nas/3.1" xmlns:ns13="urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:rapttimeline"
    xmlns:ns9="urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:ficommonmessages2"
    xmlns:ns12="urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:flowinformation"
    xmlns:ns11="urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:ficommonmessages"
    xmlns:ns10="urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:tfmrequestreplytypes"
    xmlns:ns16="http://www.fixm.aero/foundation/3.0" xmlns:ns15="http://www.fixm.aero/flight/3.0"
    xmlns:ns14="http://www.fixm.aero/base/3.0"
    xmlns:nxce="urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:tfmdatacoreelements">
    <ds:fltdOutput>
        <fdm:fltdMessage sensitivity="R" cdmPart="true" airline="RPA" major="UAL"
            sourceFacility="TFMS" sourceTimeStamp="2023-02-27T00:02:36Z" flightRef="28062242"
            acid="RPA3489" msgType="FlightControl" fdTrigger="TMI_UPDATE" depArpt="CYYZ"
            arrArpt="KEWR" sensReason="DR">
            <fdm:ncsmFlightControl>
                <nxcm:qualifiedAircraftId userCategory="COMMERCIAL" aircraftCategory="JET">
                    <nxce:aircraftId>RPA3489</nxce:aircraftId>
                    <nxce:computerId>
                        <nxce:facilityIdentifier>TFMS</nxce:facilityIdentifier>
                        <nxce:idNumber>555</nxce:idNumber>
                    </nxce:computerId>
                    <nxce:gufi>KC81743100</nxce:gufi>
                    <nxce:igtd>2023-02-26T23:30:00Z</nxce:igtd>
                    <nxce:departurePoint>
                        <nxce:airport>CYYZ</nxce:airport>
                    </nxce:departurePoint>
                    <nxce:arrivalPoint>
                        <nxce:airport>KEWR</nxce:airport>
                    </nxce:arrivalPoint>
                </nxcm:qualifiedAircraftId>
                <nxcm:etd timeValue="2023-02-27T00:11:00Z" etdType="PROPOSED" />
                <nxcm:eta timeValue="2023-02-27T00:36:00Z" etaType="ESTIMATED" />
                <nxcm:controlIndicator>CONTROL_ACTIVE</nxcm:controlIndicator>
                <nxcm:ncsmControlData>
                    <nxcm:ctd>2023-02-27T00:11:00Z</nxcm:ctd>
                    <nxcm:cta>2023-02-27T00:36:00Z</nxcm:cta>
                    <nxcm:octd>2023-02-27T00:14:00Z</nxcm:octd>
                    <nxcm:octa>2023-02-27T01:18:00Z</nxcm:octa>
                    <nxcm:controlElement>EWR</nxcm:controlElement>
                    <nxcm:controlProgramType>GDP</nxcm:controlProgramType>
                </nxcm:ncsmControlData>
            </fdm:ncsmFlightControl>
        </fdm:fltdMessage>
    </ds:fltdOutput>
</ds:tfmDataService>
```

This is the DataWeave script:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
var myInput = read(payload, 'application/xml')
output text/plain
---
"abc"
```

I keep getting this error:

```
You called the function 'AnonymousFunction' with these arguments: 
  1: Object (do {ns ds urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:tfmdataservice---{ds#tfmDataService: {ds...)
  2: String ("application/xml")

But it expects arguments of these types:
  1: String | Binary
  2: String
  3: Object


3| var myInput = read(payload, 'application/xml')
                 ^^^^
Trace:
  at main::main (line: 3, column: 15)
```

I'm not sure what part of the transformation is failing.

Comment: It's right in the error message: `(extra close tag?)`

Comment: The import `import * from dw::core::Strings` does nothing since the script is not using any functions from the String module.

Answer (score 0):

DataWeave is reading the XML input correctly The problem is that the script has an incorrect expectation on the input.

The error message explains what the problem is:

```
You called the function 'AnonymousFunction' with these arguments: 
  1: Object (do {ns ds urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:tfmdataservice---{ds#tfmDataService: {ds...)
  2: String ("application/xml")
```

The payload -the first argument- has already been read from an XML so now is a DataWeave Object, not an XML contained inside a String or a Binary stream. By using the `read()` function you are trying to parse it twice, which will not work.

The cause is not clear with the information that is available in the question. I'll assume that whatever source the payload is coming or a previous operation in the flow already parsed it.

So you can remove the `read()` operation, however if you try to output it with output format `text/plain` it will fail for similar reasons. An object can not be output to a text string. If that is your intention then you need to use the `write()` function (the opposite to `read()`) to write the Object to a simple string.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
write(payload, "application/xml")
```